# Is there a more straightforward way to search for a string while ignoring spaces?

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a function that searches a searches a string for one of a list of given words. The string being searched is generated by OCR software, that occasionally adds extra spaces between letters (depending on the font) which I need to ignore.

I currently have a function that looks like this:

```
function searchSomeText($searchTerms, $stringToBeSearched)
{
    $matches = array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($searchTerms); ++ $i)
    {
        $searchTerms[$i] = substr(chunk_split($searchTerms[$i],1,"\s*"), 0, -3);
    }
    $searchTermsString = implode("|", $searchTerms);

    if (preg_match("/\b($searchTermsString)\b/", $stringToBeSearched, $matches))
    {
        return $matches;
    }
    else { return false; }
}
```

1. Is there any way to ignore spaces *besides* adding `'\s*'` between every character in the search terms?
2. If there isn't, is there a more efficient method to add `'\s*'` after every character in the search terms but the last one other than using `chunk_split()` to add it after *every* character, and then chopping it off from the end?

### Edit

I prefer not to just strip the spaces from the `$stringToBeSearched` because in the majority of cases, where the spacing is correct, I don't want a match where a search term is contained inside of another word (hence the `'\b'`s)

Comment: It may be easier and more efficient to modify `$stringToBeSearched` with `str_replace(' ', '', $string)`, even though that doesn't "directly" answer your question.

Comment: @Sam thanks, in my particular case this won't work for me. My actual code is a little more complex than in my question. I though the simpler version would make the question clearer, but I am going to edit it now.

Comment: Hmm, nothing comes to mind initially. Your way should work, but I would agree that it is not straightforward and probably can get pretty inefficient depending on the length of `$searchTerms` and `$stringToBeSearched`.

Comment: This question would be clearer and answerable if it contained a [mcve]. @Izam

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommended strategy for what I understand of your task:

1. Do not mutate the haystack string.  Often the the string to be searched is much much longer than the needle(s) used in the search.  This potentially heavy lifting should be avoided when possible.
2. Your search terms appear to be dynamic (and likely to be coming from user input), so the characters must be escaped to prevent regex pattern breakage.  Use `preg_quote()` for this process.
3. Insert `\s*` between all non-whitespace characters in the escaped search terms (ignoring escaping slashes).
4. Then convert all sequences of one or more whitespaces to `\s+` in the search terms.
5. Now that the terms are prepared, glue them together using pipes.  Wrap the piped expression in parentheses, then wrap that capture group in wordboundary markers (`\b`).
6. Though not mentioned in your question, I recommend using case-insensitive matching.  If multibyte/unicode characters may be involved, add the `u` pattern modifier as well.

Recommended Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eL0mH))

```
function searchSomeText(array $searchTerms, string $stringToBeSearched): bool
{
    foreach ($searchTerms as &$searchTerm) {
        $searchTerm = preg_replace(
            ['/\\\\?\S\K(?=\S)/', '/\s+/'],
            ['\\s*', '\\s+'],
            preg_quote($searchTerm, '/')
        );
    }
    $pattern = '/\b(' . implode("|", $searchTerms) . ')\b/i';
    echo $pattern . "\n";
    return (bool)preg_match($pattern, $stringToBeSearched);
}

var_export(
    searchSomeText(
        ['at', 'cat ', 'the'],
        'The catheter in the hat'
    )
);
```

Output: (dynamic regex pattern & return value)

```
/\b(a\s*t|c\s*a\s*t\s+|t\s*h\s*e)\b/i
true
```